# Laravel Pluck Selected option

Tags: laravel, pluck

i wants to show selected category option in Sub-category edit form.

Am using pluck function for fetch category from database.

```
{{ Form::model($subcategories,['route'=> ['subcategories.edit',$subcategories->id],'method'=>'post']) }}

 <div class="form-group">
   {{ Form::label("","Sub Category ") }}
   {{ Form::select('category_id',$categories,null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
 </div>


 <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label("","Sub Category ") }}
    {{ Form::text('sub_category_id',old('sub_category_id'),['class'=>'form-control']) }}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">

    {{ Form::submit('UPDATE',['class'=>'form-control']) }}
 </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

How to do this ?

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: Guess i have 4 category .. 1 : "Electronics"  2. "Cloths" 3."Shoes"  and i added a sub-category item for  Category : "Cloths". when i will go for edit sub-category name for Category "Cloths" it will be show as selected option at edit page .

Comment: while using `Form::model` all the model values will be automatically populated

Comment: how  can i do this when am using to show category item by pluck function .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass array of selected values in place of 3rd arguments of select()
Ex.

```
{{ Form::select('category_id',$categories,$selected_categories,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

Comment: you mean, i should use  $subcategories->category_id as $selected_categories ?

Comment: what $subcategories->category_id contains?

Comment: $subcategories = SubCategory::findOrFail($id); in this $subcategories contains category_id , name , created_at , updated_at too. Query from controller i just minimize here to describe this.

Comment: ok just change your query like $subcategories = SubCategory::select('id','name')->where('id',$id)->get(); and pass subcategory array

Comment: please mark it as an answer so that it can help to others